# DAX How to Adjust Dates Based on Selected Value of Slicer

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

Here is my setup:

I have a date slicer that I created by doing this:

```
d_date = Calendar(min('Table_1'[CTD]),max('Table_1'[CTD])
```

Here is what my dax looks like for my variables currently:

```
var FirstVisibleVDate = Min('d_date'[Date])
var LastVisibleDate = Max('d_date'[Date])
```

**My problem(s):**

**Problem 1:** I am doing a running average, I want the running average to adjust itself based on the dates selected in the slicer. I don't think this is possible, is it?

So basically, something like this:

```
var FirstVisibleVDate = Min(value set in the date slicer)
var LastVisibleDate = Max(value set in the date slicer)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to make a selection over the slicer then that will limit the rows that are visible in the Matrix visual, you will only see the result for the dates selected, so you will have to create a duplicate disconnected Date table that will not filter the rows of the visual.

I have made a couple of forum post on this topic as well as some videos:

Posts:

1. https://forum.enterprisedna.co/t/dax-calculation-for-choose-n-specific-date/16408
2. https://forum.enterprisedna.co/t/learning-resources-about-disconnected-date-tables/15416/2
3. https://forum.enterprisedna.co/t/cumulative-transactions/11803/19

Videos:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFJThyfQt-A&ab_channel=AntrikshSharma
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLWfdlAaHlQ&ab_channel=AntrikshSharmaAntrikshSharma

Answer (score 0):

```
Date range=
Var MinDate = CALCULATE(MIN(Table1[transaction date]),ALLSELECTED(Table1[transaction date]))
Var MaxDate = CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[transaction date]),ALLSELECTED(Table1[transaction date]))
```

Source:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Capture-Time-Slicer-Minimum-Value/m-p/820372